# Callback conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Both of my callback methods have update_attributes in them.  So it looks like when calculate_rating runs it also calls modify_rating.  I only want calculate_rating to run for creating a new record and modify_rating to run only when editing and updating a record through a form.

```
     after_create :calculate_rating
     before_update :modify_rating


      def calculate_rating
      end

      def modify_rating
      end
```

Comment: Have you tried using the normal assignment methods (`self.x = 6...`) in your callbacks instead of `update_attributes`?

Comment: No, I can't assign the value like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [fine manual for `update_attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attributes):

> Updates the attributes of the model from the passed-in hash and saves the record [...]

So when you call `update_attributes`, it will try to save the object and that means that `update_attributes` is not appropriate for either of the callbacks you're using; `update_attributes` is meant to be used by controllers for mass assignment and the like.

You could replace the `update_attributes` call with simple assignments:

```
def calculate_rating
    self.attr1 = 11
    self.attr2 = 23
    #...
end
```

Comment: It gives an error: private method `write_attribute' called for #<City:0xb2fa2d0c>.  One of the attributes I want to change is part of the parent class, City.

Comment: I also get the same private method error when I try to use write_attribute to change something from the current class.

Comment: OK. Never mind I can use write_attribute on the current object, but not the parent class.